# Google Chart , ControlWrapper change placeholder

Tags: charts, google-visualization, react-google-charts

How can I change the name of the text "Choose a value"?
[Example image!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVLIR.png)
I tried it change the default or placeholder options and still the value of that text does not change. Help me please

```
sleep(500).then(() => {


                        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
                             document.getElementById('dashboard_curso')
                        );

                        var donutRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                            'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
                            'containerId': 'filter_div_curso',
                            'options': {
                                'filterColumnLabel': 'Curso',
                                'ui': {
                                    'labelStacking': 'vertical',
                                    'placeholder': 'Donuts eaten per person',
                                    label: 'Seleccione Curso',
                                    default: 'Hola Mundo'


                                }
                            }
                        });

                        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(JSON.parse(Base64.decode($('#curso_1').data('json'))));

                                    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                                        'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
                                        'containerId': 'curso_1',
                                        'options': {
                                            title: 'Asistencia por curso',
                                            vAxis: {title: '',viewWindow: { max: 1 }},
                                            hAxis: {title: 'Cursos'},
                                            isStacked: 'percent',

                                            legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },

                                            series: {
                                                0:{color:'rgb(16, 150, 24)'},
                                                1:{color:'rgb(219, 68, 55)'},
                                                2:{color:'rgb(133, 133, 133)'},

                                            }
                                        }
                                    });

                        dashboard.bind(donutRangeSlider, chart);
                        dashboard.draw(data);






                });
```

Necesito cambiar el valor por defecto de la lista

Answer (score 0):

you need to change option `ui.caption`...

```js
var donutRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
  controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
  containerId: 'filter_div_curso',
  options: {
    filterColumnLabel: 'Curso',
    ui: {
      labelStacking: 'vertical',
      caption: 'ENTER LABEL HERE'  // <-- ui.caption      
    }
  }
});
```